# Mysql Column Definition Set Max limit

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if I can set a max value in column definition of MySQL, just like we set a default value during column definition. If it can be done, how can it be achieved ? Example format:

```
int(5) not null default 1 <Something to set max value> ??
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In table definition, you can only specify maximum number of characters, for example, when you specify a column as int(5), you are limiting the field to 5 bits.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html).

To make sure the column will not accept an integer greather that 50 for exeample, you will need to use triggers for example:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON table
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.age<0 OR NEW.age>50 THEN
    CALL `Error: Wrong values for age`; -- this trick will throw an error
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: I don't think so.  "For example, INT(4) specifies an INT with a display width of four digits." It's not bits.  It's display width.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-attributes.html

Comment: yes, triggers are a solution. Though that will add an additional server call.

Answer (score 1):

You can only control the max values of a column by changing the type.

If your minimum value desired is -128 and your max required is 127, then you can go with a `TINYINT()`.  If you need between -32768 and 32767, then you need a `SMALLINT()`, and so on.

Source: [MySQL Docs: Integer Types (Exact Value) - INTEGER, INT, SMALLINT, TINYINT, MEDIUMINT, BIGINT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Presuming you are dealing with "max" and "min" integers, for instance...

> **TINYINT** : 1 byte, -128 to 127 signed, 0 to 255 unsigned
>
> **SMALLINT** : 2 bytes, -32768 to 32767 signed, 0 to 65535 unsigned
>
> **MEDIUMINT** : 3 bytes, -8388608 to 8388607 signed, 0 to 16777215 unsigned
>
> **INT** : 4 bytes, -2147483648 to 2147483647 signed, 0 to 4294967295 unsigned
>
> **BIGINT** : 8 bytes, -2^63 to 2^63-1 signed, 0 to 2^64-1 unsigned